# maven release:prepare with artifactory deploy substep fails

Tags: maven, deployment, connection, release, artifactory

after researching now for days and close to suicidal tendencies here my problem  and really really hope that i was too stupid to find the problem by myself ....

setup: windows7 / maven 3.2.3 / jdk 1.7.0_60 (64bit) / artifactory 3.5.0
Problem: 
- mvn clean install deploy --> works
- mvn release:prepare --> works
- mvn release:perform fails in substep deploy (which works standalone as mentioned before)
- POM.XML and settings.xml (for testing i took the pregenerated one from artifactory) for me. but i attached them further down....
thnx in advance for ANY help!

cheers
j.

log:

```
    .....
    [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ apps.hr ---
    [INFO] Uploading: http://vm-local-repo.fernbach-lu.dom:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/fernbach/apps.hr/0.1.4/apps.hr-0.1.4.war
    [INFO] 2/75918 KB
    [INFO] 4/75918 KB
    [INFO] 6/75918 KB
    [INFO] 8/75918 KB
    ....
    [INFO] 60/75918 KB
    [INFO] Apr 01, 2015 4:56:30 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
    [INFO] 62/75918 KB
    [INFO] INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    [INFO] 64/75918 KB
    [INFO] Apr 01, 2015 4:56:30 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
    [INFO] INFO: Retrying request
    [INFO] 66/75918 KB
    [INFO] Apr 01, 2015 4:56:30 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
    [INFO] 68/75918 KB
.....
.....
[INFO] 390/75918 KB
[INFO] 392/75918 KB
[INFO]
[INFO] Uploading: http://vm-local-repo.fernbach-lu.dom:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/fernbach/apps.hr/0.1.4/apps.hr-0.1.4.pom
[INFO] 2/2 KB
[INFO]
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time: 23.043 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2015-04-01T16:56:30+02:00
[INFO] [INFO] Final Memory: 47M/366M
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project apps.hr: Failed to
 deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.fernbach:apps.hr:war:0.1.4 from/to fs-releases (http://vm-local-repo.fernbach-lu.dom:8081
/artifactory/libs-release-local): Connection reset by peer: socket write error -> [Help 1]
...
```

SETTINGS.XML

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <localRepository>d:/fr4/maven/repo</localRepository>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>jus</username>
      <password>AP6XtRyuPNMVbXfnzP9BopSDp66</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>jus</username>
      <password>AP6XtRyuPNMVbXfnzP9BopSDp66</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://vm-local-repo:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://vm-local-repo:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://vm-local-repo:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://vm-local-repo:8081/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

POM.XML

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.fernbach</groupId>
        <artifactId>fernbach.parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>apps.hr</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>HR</name>

    <properties>
        <foundation.version>1.0.0</foundation.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fernbach</groupId>
            <artifactId>foundation.core</artifactId>
            <version>${foundation.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fernbach</groupId>
            <artifactId>foundation.web</artifactId>
            <version>${foundation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://vm-uranus1.fernbach-lu.dom/svn/fernbach-R4/apps/hr/branches/BRANCH_0.1.1</developerConnection>
        <url>scm:svn:http://vm-uranus1.fernbach-lu.dom/svn/fernbach-R4/apps/hr/branches/BRANCH_0.1.1</url>
    </scm>

</project>
```

Comment: You have a network issue: `...deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact ......Connection reset by peer: socket write error ....` or have you already deploed the release you are trying to do a second time?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! If network issue: which kind of?  Can't understand because as mentioned maven:deploy to artifactory server works like a Charme.  What's the difference to maven:deploy called directly compared to be called inside release: perform? And no: it's first try for this release.  I simply increased version with each try in order to exclude this case....

Comment: There is something fishy with the upload code. I face the issue that at some point I get a "Connection reset by peer:" but the upload is not interrupted it is continued but does only finish with a "Socket write error" after an amount of bytes for bigger than the actual archive.

Comment: Hi, have you yet any solution for this problem? I'm facing the same issue and tracked it down to version 3.2.3 of maven. In version 3.2.2 everything works well. I'm currently required to use version 3.3.3 but it has the same issue. Btw. I'm deploying to Nexus instead of Artifactory. It seems that the deploy plugin tries to deploy some artifacts twice which of course fails on repositories with disabled re-deployment. May there be an issue with the JVM forking of the release plugin?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Frankly speaking we solved the problem but i dont now anymore how. Now we are on maven 3.5.2 and release plugin works perfect (ok i know its still a messy thing but i does its job). so very sorry that i cant provide the right solution anymore. will try to documne it next time earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution in a comment of a Maven Bug that had been reported for version 3.2.3.

Here's the bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5684

The problem is the maven-source-plugin which is used to attach source jars to the project. More exactly it's the no-fork goals that cause this behavior. Using these goals the deploy plugin tries to upload the source jars twice which fails due to repository restrictions.

The solution can either be omitting the source-plugin (but then you won't have attached sources anymore) or using the forked goals (jar and test-jar) instead.

I now use the forked goals with maven 3.3.3 and I'm able to release projects again.